# Keep nested array structure the same but attach a property

Tags: javascript

I have the following nested array which I to preserve and keep the same, but also attach a property called `indexes` to each nested `items` object which stores a top-down list of indexes so I can keep track of the nested items when I flatten the array and use it elsewhere in my app. The structure looks like this:

```
[
    { 
        cat: '1'
        items: [
            {
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        cat: '2',
        items: [
            {
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        cat: '3',
        items: [
            {
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

And I'd like it to look like the following, where `indexes` starts at `0` for the first item, and for each occurrence within the `media` array attaches an incrementing number and binds it as a property.

```
[
    {
        cat: '1',
        items: [
            {
               indexes: [0],
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
               indexes: [1],
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
               indexes: [2],
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },

    {
        cat: '2',
        items: [
            {
               indexes: [3, 4],
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    },
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        cat: '3',
        items: [
            {
               indexes: [5],
                media: [
                    {
                        type: 'image'
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

What is the best way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my opinion the most elegant way would be to run through all the items using a `forEach` loop.

```js
const cats = [{
    cat: '1',
    items: [{
        media: [{
          type: 'image'
        }]
      },
      {
        media: [{
          type: 'image'
        }]
      },
      {
        media: [{
          type: 'image'
        }]
      }
    ]
  },

  {
    cat: '2',
    items: [{
      media: [{
          type: 'image'
        },
        {
          type: 'image'
        }
      ]
    }]
  },
  {
    cat: '3',
    items: [{
      media: [{
        type: 'image'
      }]
    }]
  }
];

let totalIndex = 0
cats.forEach(cat => {
  cat.items.forEach(item => {
    item.indexes = item.media.map(() => totalIndex++)
  })
})

console.log(cats)
```